# Как быстро скачать множество картинок в многопотоке?

Tags: c#, tpl

Делал сперва скачивание через Parallel.For

```
Parallel.For(0, images.Count(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10}, async (o) =>
 {
      new WebClient().DownloadFile...
 });
```

Скорость мне не понравилась.
Попробовал такой вариант

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();


        Parallel.For(0, images.Count(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1}, async (o) =>
        {
            var f = path + GetFileName(images[o]);

            tasks.Add(NewDownload(images[o], f));


        });

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

---

```
async static Task NewDownload(string hrefLink, string filename)
        {
            Axi:
            try
            {

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(hrefLink))
                using (System.Net.Http.HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {

                    if (!File.Exists(filename))
                    {
                        using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.CreateNew))
                        {
                            await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                goto Axi;
            }

        }
```

Когда `tasks` было штук 40-50 всё работало очень даже быстро, но щас у меня 20k `tasks` - и оно очень долгое время висит, нагружает проц и ничего не скачивает.

Подскажите что не так? Мб использовать другой вариант многопоточного скачивания файлов?

Comment: А ничего что 20к соединений, режут канал и скачка замедлится в N раз? И я не пойму, зачем вам столько сразу соединений и потоков? Сделайте 1 поток и скачивайте по одному, если нужна куча, то делите логику и скачивайте по 10шт к примеру за раз, а не 20к шт. за раз... Издевательство какое-то! Или я что-то просто не до понял, вопрос размытый.

Comment: @And а смысл файлы в однопотоке скачивать? у меня ssd и он не грузится на столько насколько я хочу

Comment: я хочу оптимальный вариант скачивания картинок.. быстрый

Comment: В первом комменте есть здравый момент - слишком большой поток картинок тоже плохо. Скорость скачивания каждой конкретной картинки может упасть до 1кб-сек и вы начнёте отваливаться от серверов по таймауту. Я бы ограничился 10-25 в один момент (на 100 мбит), в зависимости от сервера. И да, имейте в виду, сервер может вас так или иначе "забанить", за слишком большое число обращений к серверу или просто за трафик.

Comment: Также на сервере могут стоять ограничения на пользователя: кол-во активных подключений, кол-во обращений в единицу времени, ограничение скорости трафика, поэтому 40-50 потоков - это уже многовато. И да почитайте еще про Keep-alive подключения, а то у вас поток заканчивает работу и соединение рвется, это очень плохо когда очень много задач инициализируют новое подключение, это дополнительная бесполезная нагрузка. С Keep-alive вам бы хватило и 10-20 потоков для эффективного использования всего канала.

Comment: И еще. Использование `goto` - это моветон, особенно перезапуск потока в случае любого исключения.

Comment: У вас [классическая](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) ошибка с созданием клиента. Так же почитайте еще насчет `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.